# Python: How can I count the number of files that appear in the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a Python code that translates several html pages. After every page that was processed I direct the PRINT message to show me the name of the file and the message "translated".

Right now I get this PRINT message (Output):

```
true-value-of-myself.html translated
I-love-books.html translated
my-laptop-is-still-here.html translated
```

**But how can I count the number of files that appear in the output (filename) ? I need to change the OUTPUT so as to PRINT me something like this:**

```
true-value-of-myself.html translated (1)
I-love-books.html translated (2)
my-laptop-is-still-here.html translated (3)
```

**This is a piece of the code with the output:**

```
directory = os.fsencode(files_from_folder)

def recursively_translate(node):

    for x in range(len(node.contents)):

        if isinstance(node.contents[x], str):

            if node.contents[x].strip() != '':

                try:

                    node.contents[x].replaceWith(ts.translate(node.contents[x]))

                except Exception as e:

                    print(e)

        elif node.contents[x] != None:

            recursively_translate(node.contents[x]) 
    .....
 
for file in os.listdir(directory): 
    filename = os.fsdecode(file) 
    print(filename) 
 
print(f'{filename} translated')
```

Comment: I don't see where in the code the output is being generated, so I can't say how to count the number of files in. Or do you mean that you want the first filename to be followed by the number 1, the second with 2, etc? Your wording makes it sound like a single html file can generate multiple files, and you want to print the number that were generated. BTW, None-types are coerced to False, so since you've already checked that `node.contents[x].strip()` is a string, you can replace `if node.contents[x].strip() != '':` with `if node.contents[x].strip():`.

Comment: hello @Acccumulation I write in the request what is now the output and how must look like. It is not about `node.content` , but the exactly last part, with the print. There is where I have to make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple solution is this:

```
amount = 1

print(f'{filename} translated ({amount})')
amount += 1
```

**so in your example, replace with this:**

```
amount = 1
for file in os.listdir(directory):
...
```

and

```
print(f'{filename} translated ({amount})')
amount += 1
...
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    # Do something
    print(f"{filename} translated ({i+1})")
```

Comment: HELLO @NIGANI. I test your code, but I get the same output **`filename (4)`** even if there are only three html files.

Comment: now I get **`translated (5)`** from `({i+1}` even if there are only three html files. So, I believe something else must be change at PRINT

Comment: Check the indents before print(f"{filename} translated ({i+1})")

Comment: I get on each file the output **`translated (4)`** and **`translated (5)`** and **`translated (5)`** Should be **`1, 2, 3`**

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZMpc0w3V most of the code , also your lines are there. Also, your lines are not translate after running the code, it save me only one of three html pages

Comment: Troubles with indents. It's work. [screenshot](http://c2n.me/4cPde7P)

Comment: I believe is something from the PyScripter program. Please put the code on pastebin.com so I to copy all of it, so as to test it from there

Comment: thanks, works. But one small detail. Seems that your code is counting all the files, also `.py` or `.doc`, but I want only `html` files to be count because I have in my code the settings **`extension_file = ".html"`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235357/discussion-between-rob-rob-and-nigani).

Comment: You can use `if file.endswith(b".html"):`, but there is an easier way - https://pastebin.com/FC0cMSjB

Answer (score 0):

```
 T = (filename);
     print("Done:", T.count(f'{filename} translated'))
```

**OR**

```
c = Counter('filename')
        print(c["filename"])
```

**OR**

```
df_str="translated"
        print("DONE: 'translated': \n{}".format(df_str.count('translated')))
```